# putty correct translation on ubuntu 8.04

Tags: ssh, putty

I use a lot Midnight Commander on a Ubuntu 8.04 machine, through PuTTY.  To see correct lines drawn on the screen by `mc`, which sends line drawing characters in UTF-8, I configure PuTTY's translation as UTF-8.  But with this, `bmon` does not show the correct lines, since `bmon` sends line drawing characters encoded in Code Page 437.

How can I use just **one** translation for *both*, so that they both draw lines correctly?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Midnight Commander (`mc`) or `bmon` at all, but I took a look at them.

Basically with Putty, I have Window > Translation > Character set received set to `UTF-8`. Then during my Putty session, envvars are set to `TERM=xterm-256color` and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`,  and `mc` looks correct with line characters. It even works with the mouse, wow! However, `bmon` has the "lqqqqqk" display problem.

I then installed `ncurses-term` for the `TERM=vt-utf8`, and then ran `bmon` as `env TERM=vt-utf8 bmon`, and the display looks a bit better with line art. There is some small problem with the close dialog box, though.

I suggest shell aliasing or wrapping your `bmon` as `env TERM=vt-utf8 bmon` and leaving your LANG set to humanlang.UTF-8 alone.

Comment: some versions of terminfo recognize a "putty" terminal, but i don't know if 8.04 includes that.  my Debian Lenny system's */usr/share/terminfo/p/putty* came from package *ncurses-term* version *5.7+20081213-1*.