# PuTTY: connected to some Ubuntu server, sometimes stops going to a new line when pressing enter

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, putty, newlines

I use PuTTY in order to SSH to some Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64 server. Pressing the key  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> causes the terminal to go to a new line. However, from time to time, some program outputs some text, and afterward pressing the key  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> doesn't causes the terminal to go to a new line anymore (see demonstration below).

[image]

Is there any way to prevent that, or at least when pressing the key  <kbd>ENTER</kbd> doesn't causes the terminal to go to a new line anymore, is there anyway to reset the terminal so that <kbd>ENTER</kbd>  causes the terminal to go to a new line again?

Comment: Franck - When that happens, press `Ctrl+C`, and then type in `reset` and press `Enter`. Let me know if that helps any.

Comment: @Facebook Thanks,  type in `reset` and press `Enter` works!

Comment: Also, file a bug report against that `glances` program for leaving the terminal in a bad state after crashing ;)

Comment: By coincidence, a similar question just turned up on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398291/

Comment: Consider using cygwin and installing Terminal. Putty is very awful. For example, mc won't display correctly and won't let you select files with shift.

Comment: JorgeeFG and others will be delighted to know that the rebuttal to most of those claims about PuTTY has been here on SuperUser for years, 7 years in some cases: https://superuser.com/questions/75088/ https://superuser.com/questions/915653/  The remaining one is answered quite plainly in the PuTTY user manual in chapter 4, but has never been asked here, that I can find.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [reset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reset) command by typing in `reset` then pressing <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd> when that occurs to reset the terminal so it'll go to a new line when pressing <kbd>**`Enter`**</kbd>  again.

### Command

```
ubuntu@db200krctc:~$ ubuntu@db200krctc:~$ ubuntu@db200krctc:~$ ubuntu@db200krctc:~$
ubuntu@db200krctc:~$ reset
ubuntu@db200krctc:~$
ubuntu@db200krctc:~$
ubuntu@db200krctc:~$
```

---

### Further Resources

- [reset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/reset)

  > When invoked as **reset,** **tset** sets cooked and echo modes, turns
  >   off cbreak and raw modes, turns on newline translation and resets any
  >   unset special characters to their default values before doing the
  >   terminal initialization described above. This is useful after a
  >   program dies leaving a terminal in an abnormal state.

Answer (score 16):

The `reset` command does more than you really need here in this particular case, as your problem is merely that echo has been turned off.  `reset` actually emits control sequences to reset the terminal itself, when all that you actually *need* is to reconfigure the *line discipline* within the operating system kernel, turning echo mode back on, and not touch the *terminal* at all.

For that, simply use:

```
stty sane
```

or even just:

```
stty echo
```

`reset` addresses situations when it is actually the *terminal's own state* that needs resetting and not (just) the state of the line discipline; i.e. the tabstops have been erased, the terminal is left switched to the alternative screen buffer, an inconvenient 8-bit character set has been swapped in, and so forth.

## Further reading

- https://superuser.com/a/712668/38062
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302351/340790
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117981/

Comment: How is line discipline actually in the kernel?  This answer sounds right to me except that part of which I am very dubious.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Where else would it be?

Comment: The line discipline is actually one of the first kernel drivers ever that were configurable from userspace, Unix had `stty` and `gtty` (set and get) system calls long before they were superseded by the more general `ioctl` call.

Comment: I would have expected it to be part of the shell.  I'm a little surprised that the kernel needs to be involved.

Comment: It makes sense because it's then independent of the shell, so it'll work in other programs too. And in the early days there was no terminal program so to speak - serial consoles would interact directly with the kernel (and indeed still can).

Comment: To clarify: In the olden days the back side of /dev/tty was a physical serial port. The line discipline was managed by the kernel tty driver. With a fake terminal session or a network terminal session, /dev/tty is a psuedo-terminal and it's back side is not a physical serial port but another pseduo master device from which session data is read/written and fed to the network socket or the terminal emulator. The /dev/tty side of the pseudo terminal behaves much the same as the /dev/tty side of a real serial port. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal

Comment: ... or you could just follow the hyperlinks in the further reading section, put there for people to read more about terminals and the like.  An explanation of line disciplines, complete with pointers to books on the subject that explain even more, is a mere two hyperlinks away from this answer.  And there are plenty more on Stack Exchange.  We really do not need potted explanations in answer comments, everyone.